# Unity Canvas Randomly Scaled Itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

In the image above the Back button was in the corner of the screen and the right arrow was near the end of the canvas. I left my computer for like 30 mins and I come back to it like this, I've tried fixing it but if I scale the canvas it still isn't right and id have to adjust all the UI I have done. Is there a way to reset the canvas to normal or some kind of fix? I don't have time to rescale all my UI so it would be nice to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Canvas is set to "Scale with screen size" and that the "Back" button is pivoted ( go to pivot -> upper right corner and use ALT and then SHIFT to make sure it's pivoted ).

Other than this, if it was your cat just "Ctrl+Z" your way out or revert to a slighty older version if you are using version control.

Comment: I did scale with screen size, but that didn't really work. And for the pivoting I had set it manually, if that's not what you mean then idk, and I have a lot of UI that I would need to manually pivot . Also I tried ctrl + z as soon as i saw the messed up canvas but that didn't work..

Comment: Also another thing to note is the canvas got smaller for every scene in the game whereas the method you provided only changes an individual scene and still doesn't do everything completely right.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason unity re-scaled itself and now everything is (mostly) back to normal, I have no idea how this happened and how it fixed itself (I hadn't touched the project since this post until now (about a day later) and it was fixed)